# Decimais sem arredondar em javascript

Tags: javascript

Como faria para conseguir o seguinte resultado.

quero diminuir um numero de casas decimais após a virgula sem que o numero arredonde ?
ex: 5,8608 --> 5,860

já testei diversas funções e formas mas todas sobem o numero para 5,861.

Desde já agradeço quem puder contribuir.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Multiplica os números que queres pela ordem de grandeza igual ao número de casas decimais. Depois tiras a parte decimal e divides de novo pela mesma ordem de grandeza. Algo assim:

```js
function ajuste(nr, casas) {
  const og = Math.pow(10, casas)
  return Math.trunc(nr * og) / og;
}

console.log(ajuste(3.456, 2)); // 3.45
console.log(ajuste(4.123, 2)); // 4.12
console.log(ajuste(-4.123, 2)); // -4.12
```

EDIT: Editei a resposta para usar `Math.trunc` em vez de `Math.floor`

Comment: Esse método produz resultados inexperados com números negativos.

Comment: @v.k. obrigado, corrigi

Answer (score 6):

Complementando a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/252253/112052) (que [antes de ser editada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/252253/revisions) estava usando `Math.floor`), para funcionar também com números negativos, uma opção é usar [`Math.trunc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc) em vez de `Math.floor`:

```js
function ajuste(nr, casas) {
    const og = Math.pow(10, casas);
    return Math.trunc(nr * og) / og;
}

console.log(ajuste(-3.456, 2)); // -3.45
console.log(ajuste(-4.123, 2)); // -4.12

console.log(ajuste(3.456, 2));  //  3.45
console.log(ajuste(4.123, 2));  //  4.12
```

---

Também daria para fazer assim:

```js
function ajuste(nr, casas) {
    const sign = Math.sign(nr);
    if (sign === -1)
        nr *= -1;
    const og = Math.pow(10, casas);
    return Math.floor(nr * og) / og * sign;
}

console.log(ajuste(-3.456, 2)); // -3.45
console.log(ajuste(-4.123, 2)); // -4.12

console.log(ajuste(3.456, 2));  //  3.45
console.log(ajuste(4.123, 2));  //  4.12
```

No caso, usei [`Math.sign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign), que retorna `1` para números positivos e `-1` para negativos.

Depois, se o número é negativo, ajusto-o para que seja positivo, e no final eu multiplico pelo `sign` (assim, caso seja `-1`, o resultado volta a ser negativo).

---

Por fim, outra opção é usar `Math.floor` ou `Math.ceil` dependendo do sinal do número:

```js
function ajuste(nr, casas) {
    const og = Math.pow(10, casas);
    return (nr > 0 ? Math.floor(nr * og) : Math.ceil(nr * og)) / og;
}

console.log(ajuste(-3.456, 2)); // -3.45
console.log(ajuste(-4.123, 2)); // -4.12

console.log(ajuste(3.456, 2));  //  3.45
console.log(ajuste(4.123, 2));  //  4.12
```

Answer (score -3):

let nteste=5.8608
console.log(nteste.toFixed(3))  //dessa maneira arredonda para 5.861

let numero=5.8608

let numero2=numero*1000  // como nesse caso tu quer 5.860 então é preciso guardar na variavel numero2 todos esses algarismos multiplicando por 1000
numero2=parseInt(numero2)/1000  // o parseInt é necessário para que apenas a parte inteira seja dividida por 1000

console.log(numero2.toFixed(3)) // estou fixando 3 casas decimais

Comment: Estou aprendendo a programar e essa foi a maneira que consegui resolver o seu problema. espero ter ajudado!