# Cortar os zeros desnecessários de uma string, sem toFixed()

Tags: javascript

Como faço para eliminar os valores zero de uma string? Exemplos:

```
"100,50" >> "100,5"
"2,00" >> "2"
```

Sendo que apenas nos casos em que tem o zero no final. Por exemplo, não quero arredondar com aquele `toFixed(1)`, pois comprometeria casos do tipo "100,56" >> "100,6".

**Complementando a situação do meu problema:**

Estou utilizando um framework para validar alguns dados de um sistema, e ai tem um método para comparar a propriedade de um objeto, e todas as propriedades do objeto são strings.

Por exemplo a propriedade VALUE é o valor que esta no objeto do sistema e tem o valor "100,5". E "100,50" é o que esta numa base de dados. Note que os dois são strings, tanto o sistema quanto a base de dados. Ai percebi que esta dando erro com casos do tipo "100,50" e "2,00".

Ai uso o método assim:
`compare(objeto,propriedade, cmp, "100,50")`, onde a propriedade é o campo que tem o "100,5".

Comment: `new Number("100.50")` ou `parseFloat('100.50')` ou `"100.50".replace(/(?:,?0+)$/g, '')`

Comment: Porque os valores estão com virgula? Eles possivelmente não começam com ponto? Algo como 100.5 ? Será que a maneira que você abordou não esta tentando resolver um problema que talvez nem devesse existir?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se o seu valor já estiver no tipo string, você pode utilizar uma expressão regular como esta:

```
/(^0+(?=\d))|(,?0+$)/g
```

Que irá remover todos os zeros do final de uma string  e a vírgula, caso necessário.

Veja:

```js
function stripZeros(str) {
  return str.replace(/(^0+(?=\d))|(,?0+$)/g, '');
}

console.log(stripZeros('100,50')); // 100,5
console.log(stripZeros('2,00')); // 2
console.log(stripZeros('001,00')); // 1
console.log(stripZeros('00,10')); // 0,1
```

Uma outra opção é converter a string para o tipo `number`, o que remove os zeros desnecessários e, por fim, convertê-lo novamente para o formato desejado:

```js
function stripZeros(str) {
  return parseFloat(str.replace(',', '.'))
    .toString()
    .replace('.', ',');
}

console.log(stripZeros('100,50')); // 100,5
console.log(stripZeros('2,00')); // 2
console.log(stripZeros('001,00')); // 1
console.log(stripZeros('00,10')); // 0,1
```

Comment: work like a charm, obrigado

Comment: Vendo vários casos eu imaginei que só iria sair com expressão regular por se tratar de string. Mas encontrei apenas para cortar os zeros da frente.
Declarar como um numero e depois converter para string (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3613112/9585539) não iria resolver também para o meu caso.

Comment: @anijahzarri Não é só porque é string que a única solução é uma regex. Deixei uma [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/459884/112052) sem regex pra vc ver que há outras opções :-)

Answer (score 3):

Existe uma outra opção, sem regex.

Primeiro você precisa transformar a string em número. Infelizmente [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) só aceita o ponto como separador decimal, então não tem muito como escapar de um [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) para trocar a vírgula por ponto.

Depois, não ficou claro quantas casas decimais podem ter na string (é sempre duas, pode ter outra quantidade?), então podemos usar um pequeno "truque" (na verdade nada mais é que [a boa e velha matemática](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/252253/112052)) para deixar o número com apenas 2 casas decimais, sem arredondamento. Para isso, basta multiplicar o número por 100, arredondar para baixo e depois dividir por 100 novamente - de maneira mais geral, para uma quantidade `x` de casas, basta fazer esses cálculos com 10<sup>x</sup> (mas se as strings sempre vem com 2 casas, esse passo não é necessário).

Por fim, para formatar o número, usamos [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString), bastando escolher um *locale* adequado (que por sua vez controla alguns aspectos, como por exemplo o caractere usado como separador decimal), além da quantidade de casas decimais a serem exibidas. Ficaria assim:

```js
function arredonda(s, maxCasas) {
    let n = parseFloat(s.replace(',', '.'));

    // deixar o número com apenas 'maxCasas' casas decimais, sem arredondar
    let fator = Math.pow(10, maxCasas);
    n = Math.floor(n * fator) / fator;

    let opcoes = {
        minimumFractionDigits: 0,
        maximumFractionDigits: maxCasas,
        useGrouping: false
    };
    return n.toLocaleString('pt-BR', opcoes );
}

for (const n of [ '2,00', '100,50', '3', '12,347', '12345,6789' ])
    console.log(`${n} => ${arredonda(n, 2)}`);
```

A saída é:

```
2,00 => 2
100,50 => 100,5
3 => 3
12,347 => 12,34
12345,6789 => 12345,67
```

A opção `useGrouping: false` (descrita [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat)) faz com que não seja usado o separador de milhares (seu valor *default* é `true`, então se ela for omitida, o último número seria exibido como `12.345,67`).

Usei o locale `pt-BR` (português do Brasil), que usa a vírgula como separador decimal. Assim, a formatação já é feita com o caractere correto (se você usar outro *locale*, como por exemplo `en-US` (inglês americano), será usado o ponto em vez da vírgula). E as demais opções controlam a quantidade de casas decimais a serem exibidas (usando mínimo zero e máximo `maxCasas`, não são exibidas casas decimais quando o número não tem a parte decimal, por exemplo).

Como já dito, caso todas as strings sempre tenham 2 casas decimais, não é necessário fazer o arredondamento, bastando chamar `toLocaleString` logo após o `parseFloat`.

---

Caso esteja trabalhando com valores monetários, é interessante ler [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11018/112052).

E se você só quer comparar as strings "100,50" e "100,5" com base nos seus valores numéricos, nem precisava gerar a string final, bastava transformar ambos em números (fazendo o `parseFloat` com `replace`) e depois compará-los.

Answer (score 0):

Adicionei também como remover os zeros antes e depois da vírgula de um número no formato de string:

```js
function stripZeros(str) {
  str = str.replace(/^0+(?=\d)/, '') //remove zeros da frente
  return str.replace(/,?0+$/,''); //remove zeros atras
}

console.log(stripZeros('100,50')); // 100,5
console.log(stripZeros('2,00')); // 2
console.log(stripZeros('001,00')); // 1
console.log(stripZeros('00,10')); // 0,1
```